# How do I get the ID in onget and the use handler in asp.net core razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor page for editing information in which I take the ID as input in onget. On this page, I want my handler to be called if a button is clicked. To do this, I need to use @page "{handler?}" in the code. But I also need to use @page "{id}" to get the ID. How is it possible to use both on one page?

```
@page "{id}"
<form asp-page-handler="test" method="post">

         <button >test </button>

</form>
```

```
 public IActionResult OnPosttest()

{
      //my code
}
```

```
public void OnGet(long id)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add @page "{handler?}",

You just need to change OnPost**t**est to OnPost**T**est, use **capitalization** instead, that is the razor

page naming convention, and then the method can be called.

> But I also need to use @page "{id}" to get the ID. How is it possible to use both on one page?

you can use this format

```
@page "{handler?}/{id?}"
```

to use both on one page.

Comment: I tested this, but when calling the page,  for id zero is passed :(

Comment: How you call the page, Url or form with data? If url, use https://localhost:**/(pagename)?id=1 .  If form, you should bind your id data, and please show your related code.